# Obscure encoding WSGI error when upgrading: "write() argument must be a bytes instance"

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I'm trying to create a duplicate of a django app I wrote, hosted on a different VPS provider with up-to-date everything (Ubuntu 16.04, django 1.9.5, python 3.5). It was successfully deployed using the previous version of everything in the stack (Ubuntu 15.1, django 1.9.4, python 3.4).

I've got a problem with the WSGI content, which I narrowed down to this obscure error when run the development server `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` (below is a GET request to `/login` but the error is the same with a fake URL not matched in urls.py):

```
[04/May/2016 09:33:54] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 266, in write
    "write() argument must be a bytes instance"
AssertionError: write() argument must be a bytes instance
```

I gather that this would be an encoding error, but why does it occur, and how can I fix it? Looking at the source of `handlers.py` I can't see why `finish_response` data would have incorrect encoding. I've copied the three functions referenced in the error (with the relevant lines marked) for convenience:

```
def run(self, application):
    """Invoke the application"""
    # Note to self: don't move the close()!  Asynchronous servers shouldn't
    # call close() from finish_response(), so if you close() anywhere but
    # the double-error branch here, you'll break asynchronous servers by
    # prematurely closing.  Async servers must return from 'run()' without
    # closing if there might still be output to iterate over.
    try:
        self.setup_environ()
        self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
        ###line 138###
        self.finish_response()
    except:
        try:
            self.handle_error()
        except:
            # If we get an error handling an error, just give up already!
            self.close()
            raise   # ...and let the actual server figure it out.

def finish_response(self):
    """Send any iterable data, then close self and the iterable

    Subclasses intended for use in asynchronous servers will
    want to redefine this method, such that it sets up callbacks
    in the event loop to iterate over the data, and to call
    'self.close()' once the response is finished.
    """
    try:
        if not self.result_is_file() or not self.sendfile():
            for data in self.result:
                ###line 180###
                self.write(data)
            self.finish_content()
    finally:
        self.close()

def write(self, data):
    """'write()' callable as specified by PEP 3333"""

    assert type(data) is bytes, \
        ###line 266###
        "write() argument must be a bytes instance"

    if not self.status:
        raise AssertionError("write() before start_response()")

    elif not self.headers_sent:
        # Before the first output, send the stored headers
        self.bytes_sent = len(data)    # make sure we know content-length
        self.send_headers()
    else:
        self.bytes_sent += len(data)

    # XXX check Content-Length and truncate if too many bytes written?
    self._write(data)
    self._flush()
```

Comment: What exactly should have been outputted there? Is there a short testcase with which you can reproduce the error? Ah, I didn't saw you get the same error if you should get a 404.

Comment: I should get some sort of http200 with a HttpResponse being sent via the test server. Instead I get an exception and I don't know why I would get it - the error is obscure and I don't know where to look to debug.

Comment: are you using the standard Django login?

Comment: It wasn't the standard login view, I wrote my own. In the end though I couldn't solve the problem and rebuild the venv with django 1.9.6 and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

i had (maybe) the same issue and it was not related to inner wsgiref code: your response must be a list. if it is not a list, that very error is triggered. here is an exemple from the wsgiref docs

```
from wsgiref.util import setup_testing_defaults
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

# A relatively simple WSGI application. It's going to print out the
# environment dictionary after being updated by setup_testing_defaults
def simple_app(environ, start_response):
    setup_testing_defaults(environ)

    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')]
    start_response(status, headers)

    #return b'fail' <- triggers: write() argument must be a bytes instance
    return [b'win']

with make_server('', 8000, simple_app) as httpd:
    print("Serving on port 8000...")
    httpd.serve_forever()
```